# count the distance between to strings in an array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

i have an array

```
line_one = ["flinders street", "richmond", "east richmond", "burnley", "hawthorn", "glenferrie"]

user_input1 = "flinders street"
user_input2 = "glenferrie"
```

how could I count the distance between the two strings?
expected output 5.

Comment: Could any give value possibly exist more than once in your array?

Comment: no the same string wouldn't appear twice.

Comment: Are these stations along a railway / bus line and you want to calculate the number of stops between two of them? Just asking for some context.

Comment: How do you define "distance"? Levenshtein distance? Jaccard? Cosine?

Comment: I see 8 strings in your code. 6 are stored in an array, and two are stored in separate variables. What is the distance between strings anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind:

```
line_one = ["flinders street", "richmond", "east richmond", "burnley", "hawthorn", "glenferrie"]

user_input1 = "flinders street"
user_input2 = "glenferrie"

(line_one.find_index(user_input1) - line_one.find_index(user_input2)).abs
#=>  5
```

Comment: @engineersmnky, always test!

Answer (score 0):

```
line_one = ["flinders street", "richmond", "east richmond", "burnley", "hawthorn", "glenferrie"]
```

Code

```
p (line_one.index("flinders street")...line_one.index("glenferrie")).count
```

output

```
5
```

Comment: That seems the same as `(line_one.index("flinders street")...line_one.index("glenferrie")).count`, but more importantly, what if `user_input1 = "glenferrie"; user_input2 = "flinders street"`?

Comment: I don't think they would be checking something like you say. and I modified the answer according to your suggestion, that looks correct.